# Is it possible to read results of the XmlSerializer being sent by HTTPClient?

Tags: c#, httpclient, xmlserializer

I am using an extension method to post xml using the HTTPClient which works great.

My question: Is it possible to read, log, or display the results of the XmlSerializer data that is being sent/posted ?

```
    public static class HttpExtensions  {
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsXmlWithSerializerAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, string requestUri, T value)
    {
        return client.PostAsync(requestUri
                                , value
                                , new XmlMediaTypeFormatter { UseXmlSerializer = true }
                                );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PostAsync` hides the actually sent `HttpRequestMessage` from you, though you can retrieve it from the response, too so you can trace both the request and response contents:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, value, formatter);
Log(response);
```

If you really want to log the request only, create the request manually:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
request.Content = new StreamContent(myXmlStream);
Log(request);
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
Log(response);
```

And now you can create one or two `Log` overloads. I show it for the response, which includes both the request and response log. This is independent from the format, works for both XML and json content.

```
protected virtual void Log(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    // Use any log/trace engine here, this example uses Debug
    Debug.WriteLine($"Response of the API Call [{response.RequestMessage.Method}] {response.RequestMessage.RequestUri}: {response.StatusCode} {FormatResponse(response)}");
}

private static string FormatResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    result.AppendLine();
    result.AppendLine("Original request:");
    result.AppendLine(FormatHttpMessage(response.RequestMessage.Headers, response.RequestMessage.Content));
    result.AppendLine();
    result.AppendLine("Obtained response:");
    result.AppendLine(FormatHttpMessage(response.Headers, response.Content));
}

private static string FormatHttpMessage(HttpHeaders headers, HttpContent content)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    var headersString = headers.ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headersString))
    {
        result.AppendLine("Headers:");
        result.AppendLine(headersString);
        result.AppendLine();
    }

    if (content != null)
    {
        result.AppendLine("Content:");
        result.AppendLine(content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
Download and install [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) , then filter your `requestUri` , you can monitor all transferring data such you serialized xml.